# Accessing an API that downloads a file

Tags: node.js, api, csv

I'm trying to use this API from w4.com
They have a few different options, but ultimately they all end up downloading a file (either as a CSV, XML etc.).

I need to write a script that will pull data from the API every so often, but I am at a complete loss of how to do this without manually going and downloading the CSV every time.

I'm using Node.js, is there some way I can use `$http` to do the request and then actually access the file they pass me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just issue a GET request to the corresponding url and it will download the file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fileUrl = "your-w3-file-url";
var request = http.get(fileUrl, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear. I know how to do that. What I need to know is how to access the data they sent me in the file.